# Function that forms an Arithmetic Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, functional-equations

I've been working on this problem for a while:

> Let $n > 2$ be an integer. Let $f$ be a function from the set of all integers to itself with the following property: If the integers $a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots, a_n$ form an arithmetic progression, then the numbers $f(a_1), f(a_2), \dots f(a_n)$ form an arithmetic progression in some order (that's possibly constant). Determine all values $n$ such that the only functions $f$ with the above property are the functions in this form: $f(x)=bx+c$, where $b$ and $c$ are integers.

My work is most likely trivial, but I wrote $a_1, a_2, \dots a_n$ as $a_1, a_1+x, a_1+2x, \dots, a_1+(n-1)x$. Then, applying $f(x)=bx+c$ to each term in the sequence, I got that the values of the sequence were
$$ba_1+c, b(a_1+x)+d, \dots, b(a_1+(n-1)x)+d.$$ However, I'm unable to make more progress.

Thanks for any form of help!

Comment: For $n$ prime, there is a non-linear function that satisfies the conditions. Try finding it.

Comment: Thanks, I found a non-linear function for $n$ prime. How would I show that there isn't a non-linear function for composite $n$ though?

Answer (score 1):

(Fill in the gaps as needed, especially when it says "Show that". If you're stuck, explain what you've tried.)

Claim: For $n$ prime, the function $f(a) = ( a \mod n )$  satisfies the conditions.

Proof: Show that any AP of length $n$, taken modulo $n$ (prime), is either

1. A constant sequence, or
2. $\{ 1 , 2, \ldots , n-1, n \}$.

In either case, $ f(a_i)$ forms an AP. $_\square$

---

Suppose that for some $n$, we had such a non-linear function $f(x)$.

Suppose that the function is not injective.

Let $k$ be the minimum positive integer such that there exists $ |a-b| = k$ and $ f(a) = f(b)$. WLOG, let $ a < b$.

- Case 1:  $k < n$.
  Show that $ f(x) $ is a constant, which is a contradiction.
- Case 2: $ k > n$.
  Consider the AP's $ \{ f(a+i + j)\}_{j=0}^{n-1}$ going from $ i = 0$ to $ i = k+1 - n > 1$.
  Since $ f(a) \neq f( a +n)$, and $ \{ f(a+j)_{j=0}^{n-1} \}, \{ f(a+1+j)_{j=0}^{n-1} \}$ both form an non-constant AP, show that $ \{ f(a), f(a + n) \} $ must be the minimum and maximum of $ \{ f(a+j) \} _{j=0}^n$.
  WLOG, let $ f(a) < f(a+n)$, so $ f(a)$ is the minimum and $f(a+n)$ is the maximum.
  Applying the same logic to $ f(a+1) \neq f(a+1+n)$, $\{ f(a+1), f(a +1+ n) \} $ must be the minimum and maximum of $ \{ f(a+j) \} _{j=1}^{n+1}$. Since $f(a+1) < f(a+n)$, hence $f(a+1)$ is the minimum and $f(a+1+n)$ is the maximum, so $ f(a+n) < f(a+n+1)$.
  We thus get the chain of inequalities $ f(a) < f(a+n) < f(a+n+1) < \ldots < f(a+k)$, contradicting the choice of $k$. Thus, no such function is possible.
- Case 3: $ k = n$.
  Show that for any non-trivial divisor $ d \mid n$, $ 1 < d < n$ , we have $ f(a) = f( a + \frac{k}{d} )  $. Thus, if $n$ is composite, no such function is possible.

Hence, a non-injective non-linear function could exist only if $k=n$ and $n$ is prime.

Now, suppose that the function is injective.
Using the same argument as in Case 2, show that

> Assuming $f(0 ) < f(n)$,
> We thus get the chain of inequalities $ f(n) < f(n+1) < f(n+2) < \ldots $.
> Similarly, we get the chain of inequalities $ \ldots < f(n-2) < f(n-1 ) < f(n) $.

(Show that) $f(x) = f(0) + x ( f(1) - f(0) ) $ is a linear function.

Hence, a non-linear function could exist only if $k=n$ and $n$ is prime. We have shown above that such a solution exists.

---

For prime $n$, we have the following solution:

Let $ g: \mathbb{Z_n} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z_n}$ be a bijection. Then, $ f(a) = b \times g ( a \mod{n} ) + c $ satisfies the conditions.
The solution at the top is the identity $ g(a \mod{n} ) = a \mod {n}$ and $b = 1, c = 0 $.
I believe that in Case 3, using the technique similar to Case 2, we can show that $f(x+n) = f(x)$ for all $x$, from which the solution follows.

Comment: When you say "Let $$  be the minimum positive integer such that there exists $|−|=$ and $()=()$", what are $a$ and $b$? They don't seem to be the previous definitions of $a$ and $b$ in this problem.

Comment: @bruiseking It's an abuse of notation / the variables are doing double duty. My definitions of $a, b$ have nothing to do with the problem, and it's just $f(a) = f(b)$. Sorry!

Comment: Sorry I'm still confused about the definition of $k$. We don't know if $f(a)=f(b)$ is possible, since $f(x)$ could be some weird injective function (which makes $a-b=0$). Also, are $a$ and $b$ any nonnegative integer or are they part of the original sequence $a_1, a_2, \dots a_n$?

Comment: @bruiseking Oh, good point. Hm, I forgot to put that in.... $a,b$ are any integers (not necessarily non-negative). The "sequence $a_1, a_2, \ldots a_n$" is just a place holder / dummy variables.

Comment: @bruiseking You should be able to finish out the rest. If you're stuck, show your work and what you've tried.